Why don't SVG filters take into account the position of the SVG's viewBox, since they do take into account its size?


<svg viewBox="60 0 200 40">
  <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
  </filter>

  <path d="M 70 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 100 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 130 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 160 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 190 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 220 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 250 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />

  <path d="M 70 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 100 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 130 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 160 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 190 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 220 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 250 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
</svg>



The above SVG is supposed to have two rows of seven lines each. The bottom row, with no filter, shows up as intended. The top row, with a Gaussian blur filter, is missing half of the next-to-last line and all of the last line.
It looks like this is happening because the filter region is getting its size from the viewBox, but its position is tied to the origin. The spec says this:

The initial value for x and y is -10%.
The initial value for width and height is 120%.

This is consistent with the width being 200 and it cutting off right through the middle of the line at x-coordinate 220. As further evidence of this, if I add 1000 to every x-coordinate, then the filtered lines completely disappear, but the unfiltered ones are fine:


<svg viewBox="1060 0 200 40">
  <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
  </filter>

  <path d="M 1070 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1100 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1130 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1160 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1190 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1220 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1250 5 l 0 10" style="filter: url(#blur); stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />

  <path d="M 1070 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1100 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1130 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1160 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1190 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1220 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 1250 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
</svg>



I know I can work around this by calculating -10% myself relative to the viewBox's origin (60 - 0.1*200 = 40 for the first example, and 1060 - 0.1*200 = 1040 for the second example) and then setting it as the x attribute on the filter, but this feels like it's duplicating information and creating unnecessary work if I later want to change the viewBox. Is there a better way of fixing this?

Just for clarity: why not use objectBoundingBox (the default) instead of userSpaceOnUse?

@RobbyCornelissen The real-world context I ran into this with is a more complicated filter where userSpaceOnUse is important.

@RobbyCornelissen I just edited the question to use a slightly different example that now really does require that.

Why? Because the authors of the SVG spec wrote it that way over 20 years ago.

I've just opened an issue regarding the spec, since to me it seems there is no clear rule what percentage values are relative to in this case.

@ccprog See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866655 Note, it may well be too late to do anything about this now.

As I just commented there, my point is not about changing behavior but clarity for users: the <pattern> spec explicitely names the viewport as the reference for percentage values, the <filter> spec lacks that sentence.

My suggestion would be to use transform/translate to move the individual paths (or whatever shape you need). Would that work out in your context?


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="60 0 200 40">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(70 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(100 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(130 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(160 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(190 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(220 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <path d="M 0 5 l 0 10" transform="translate(250 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
  </g>
  <path d="M 70 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 100 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 130 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 160 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 190 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 220 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  <path d="M 250 25 l 0 10" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
</svg>



And just to show that the filter also works with a larger shape:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="60 0 200 40">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M 0 5 h 180" transform="translate(70 0)" filter="url(#blur)" />
  </g>
  <path d="M 0 5 h 180" transform="translate(70 25)"
    style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
</svg>



